# В чём у меня заключаетья ошибка я не могу понять

Tags: php

У меня ошибка в 12 строке

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>BYOWL | Login in</title>
    </head>
    <body background="assets/img/background.jpg">
    <!--Форма авторизации-->
    <?php
        if($_COOKIE['user']==''):
    ?>

                        <form action="" method="" style="border: 5px solid white; border-radius: 10px;">
                            <label>Login</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="enter login">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="enter password">
                            <button>Sign in</button>
                            <p>
                                Don't have an account? - <a href="register.php" style="padding: 10px 0 0 0;">create an
                                    account</a>
                            </p>

                        </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

а вот где я сделал куки

```
<?php
$login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','byowl');
$result=$mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 'login'='$login' AND 'password'='$password'") ;
$user=$result->fetch_assoc();
if (count ($user)==0) {
    echo "User is not found";
    exit();
}
    setcookie ("user", $user['login'], time()+3600,"/");
$mysql->close();
header('location: /' );
?>
```

Comment: _У меня ошибка в 12 строке_ - это где и какая ошибка?

Comment: в том то и дело то что оштбки нет а он её выдаёт когда через локал хост загружаю страницу

Answer (score 1):

> выдаёт когда через локал хост загружаю страницу

Что конкретно выдаёт?

Notice: Неопределенный индекс? (Notice: Undefined index).
Если да, то перед сравнением добавьте проверку наличия данного индекса.

**Дополняю, отвечая на вопрос, заданный в комментарии:**

Проверить существование индекса, что бы не вылетал Notice можно разными функциями: `array_key_exists('user', $_COOKIE)`, `empty($_COOKIE['user'])`.

В вашем случае для более корректной проверки вам следует `$_COOKIE['user']==''` заменить на `empty($_COOKIE['user'])`.
Суть проверки останется той же и уведомление появляться не будет, т.к. **empty** под капотом проверяет и на существование данного ключа и на пустоту его значения.

Comment: напиши как это?

Comment: @Сергей, дополнил ответ. Перечитайте. Если останутся вопросы - пишите

Comment: давайте свяжемся в другой соц сети мне просто нужна ещё помощь

Comment: вот если что моя страница - https://vk.com/youdied0